# Jquery ui autocomplete not working with rails 4.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working on a Rails 4.2 app (with Bootstrap) and trying to set up autocomplete in a text field. I'm following the Railscasts autocomplete association [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA):

My application.js looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

and my application.css contains:

```
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

The model "modelname" contains a text field "email".
In the view file new.html.erb for modelname I have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@modelname) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "EmailId" %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the app\assets\javascripts\modelnames.coffee file I've added the autocomplete source:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#modelname_email').autocomplete
        source: ['abc', 'def', 'ade', 'dge', 'ghi']
```

But as I start typing in the "modelname_email" text field the autocomplete doesn't show up.

Have I missed any required step?

**EDIT**: I've also read that Turbolinks sometimes causes issues with respect to jquery, could that be the cause here? I tried some changes but they had no effect.

Comment: Anybody? I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get jquery-ui's autocomplete to work so I used the [rails4-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) gem and it's worked so far.

Following are the steps I followed:

1. In the gemfile, add the following entry:

   gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
2. In app\assets\javascripts\application.js, add the following entry (I added it before the "//= require turbolinks" entry):

   //= require autocomplete-rails
3. In config\routes.rb (model name is "employee" and it's field on which I require autocomplete is "email" ):

   ```
   resources :employees do
       get :autocomplete_employee_email, :on => :collection
   end
   ```
4. In the employees\new.html.erb (this contains the text field for "email" where I require the autocomplete to work) (Please see comment for the code):
5. And finally in the app\controllers\employees_controller.erb:

   def autocomplete_employee_email

   term = params[:term]

   if term && !term.empty?

   items = Employeee.select("distinct email").
   where("LOWER(email) like ?", term.downcase + '%').
   limit(10).order(:email)

   else

   items = {}

   end

   render :json => json_for_autocomplete(items, :email)

   end

Comment: Point 4's code is: <%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
<%= f.label "Email" %>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :email, autocomplete_employee_email_employees_path %>
<% end %>

Comment: I tried writing the above code in the post but it automagically disappeared and I can't find a way to make it show, so wrote it in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery needs to be listed prior to `require_tree` in your manifests.

application.css

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```